# Can we move the picture upwards?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I want to add a picture a text and I have the following code:

```
\title{\foreignlanguage{english}{Ackermann's function}}

\date{ }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
 \begin{figure}[h!]
 \central
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{ackermann.jpg}
\end{figure}


 Name: ...

 Prof.: ...

 Subject: ... 

 University: ... 


\end{frame}
```

Can we move the picture more upwards?

Is there such a command?

**EDIT:**

Does the command

```
\raisebox{4mm}[0pt][0pt]{ 
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{ackermann.jpg}\par 
\foreignlanguage{english}{Wilhelm Ackermann,1896-1962}} 
}
```

also work for the template "article" instead of the article "beamer" ??

When I write this command it only appears the following:

> [scale=0.35]ackermann.jpg
>
> Wilhelm Ackermann,1896-1962

but the picture doesn't appear.

I have written the following commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{mylemma}{Λήμμα}

\title{\foreignlanguage{english}{Ackermann's function}}
%\author{ }
\date{ } 

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\raisebox{4mm}[0pt][0pt]{
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{ackermann.jpg}\par
\foreignlanguage{english}{Wilhelm Ackermann,1896-1962}}
}
```

Comment: It seems like you might be using [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). Could you update your code to reflect a minimal example we can copy-and-paste-and-compile? Code snippets are sometimes misleading since they don't provide a complete scope of the problem.

Comment: What 'recent changes' have there been in the last 10 days which have invalidated [Harish Kumar's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238730/)? This strikes me as *prima facie* unlikely but I'm not a MiKTeX user. (I assume you must be since TeX Live is currently frozen and is not currently changing in any way at all.)

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. You are missing `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Ackermann's function}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \titlepage
 \raisebox{2mm}[0pt][0pt]{%
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}}
}

%% \raisebox{distance}[height][depth]{text}


 Name: ...

 Prof.: ...

 Subject: ...

 University: ...


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust `2mm` as suitable.

Or you can also use `\vspace{length}`

```
\begin{frame}[t]
  \titlepage
 \vspace{-3cm}
 {\centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}\par
}


 Name: ...

 Prof.: ...

 Subject: ...

 University: ...


\end{frame}
```

To add a name, use a `\parbox` instead of `\makebox` like this:

```
\titlepage
 \raisebox{2mm}[0pt][0pt]{%
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}\par
Some name}
}
```

or

```
\titlepage
 \vspace{-3cm}
 {\centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}\par Some name \par
}
```

---

## Edit for the edited question

You are missing the `\usepackage{graphicx}`. The following works for me with miktex 2.9 updated 4 days ago.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{mylemma}{Λήμμα}

\title{\foreignlanguage{english}{Ackermann's function}}
%\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\noindent
\raisebox{4mm}[0pt][0pt]{%
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image}\par
\foreignlanguage{english}{Wilhelm Ackermann,1896-1962}}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Also how could we write under the picture a description of it?? I want to write the name of the person of the picture... Which is the command?? @HarishKumar

Comment: @MaryStar Please see the edit.

Comment: Now I use an other template, an article... Do I have to use the same command to add a picture and a name under the picture?? @HarishKumar When I write the command above it appears only the name of the image (ackermann.jpg)

Comment: @MaryStar Same method works. Make sure that you don't have `draft` as the option to graphicx.

Comment: Do you mean at an usepackage ?? @HarishKumar

Comment: I don't have draft.

Comment: @HarishKumar Why has Community not given you half of the available bounty? Your answer is both accepted by the OP and has 5 times as many votes as mine. In fact, I thought that since your answer was accepted, Community should give you the fully bounty but you surely you are meant to get the half?

Comment: @cfr: I have no idea `:-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar I've flagged my answer for the moderators pointing out what I just said to you.

Comment: @cfr: It is Ok (I am not worried that much about the bounties `:-)`).. But thank you. You are very nice. `:-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar I'm not nice: it isn't fair!

Comment: @cfr You are nice because you feel that it isn't fair `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

It is not at all clear from your question what code you are using so it is almost impossible to say what the problem might be. Perhaps you have not loaded the `graphicx` package. Perhaps you are using `beamer` commands in a document which uses the `article` class. Perhaps something else.

This is an example of a custom title in the `article` class which emulates the layout on your slide. It uses `titling` and some custom commands to do this.

Note that `\institute` and `\subject` are defined in `beamer`, I think, but certainly not in `article`. Here we define them and use them in a customised `\maketitle` via hooks provided by the `titling` package.

`\instructor` is another command defined here and used by the same mechanism, but I don't think this exists in `beamer` so there is less potential, I hope, for confusion.

```
\documentclass[american,british]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,babel,titling}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\my@instructor{}
\newcommand*\instructor[1]{\renewcommand*\my@instructor{#1}}
\newcommand*\my@uni{}
\newcommand*\institute[1]{\renewcommand*\my@uni{#1}}
\newcommand*\my@subject{}
\newcommand*\subject[1]{\renewcommand*\my@subject{#1}}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookb{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}\par
    \foreignlanguage{american}{Wilhelm Ackermann,1896-1962}\bigskip\par}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\large Name: }
\postauthor{%
  \bigskip\par
  Instructor: \my@instructor\bigskip\par
  Subject: \my@subject\bigskip\par
  Institution: \my@uni\par
\end{flushleft}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author{A. N. Author}
\instructor{Dr.~Seuss}
\subject{Astrozoology}
\institute{Martian Institute of Aardvarks}
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: custom title]

Comment: Now the picture appears!! Do you maybe know if we can make the picture bigger?? @cfr

Comment: @MaryStar Well, you have `scale=0.35` which makes it only 35% the size of the original. If you used, say, `scale=.5` it would be 50% the size of the original.